# Independence of Least Squares Estimators (LSE)

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, variance, covariance, least-squares

Consider the linear regression equation $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \beta_2x_i^2 + \epsilon_i$ in the quadratic polynomial model with the independent normal noise $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Assume that the observations of the response values $y_i$ are available at the design points $x_1 = -10, x_2 = -9, ... , x_{20} = 9, x_{21} = 10$. Prove that the Least Squares Estimator (LSE) of $\beta_1$ is independent of the LSE of $\beta_2$.

Comment: Note that this independence is equivalent to covariance being 0 *only* because $\hat{\beta}$ is Gaussian. Now, if you have the covariance matrix of $\hat{\beta}$, all you have to do is check that the corresponding entries are $0$: I.e. check that $2,3$'rd entry of $Var(\hat{\beta})$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Great point ! I'd forgotten for some time what that matrix actually encodes. And I'm glad you made the point about $\hat{\beta}$ being Gaussian: it turns out I neglected this in making the jump from covariance zero $\Rightarrow$ independence. Thank you so much. (=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know
$$\widehat{\beta}=\beta+\left(X'X\right)^{-1}X'\epsilon$$

which clearly mans that $\widehat{\beta}$ is normally distributed with mean zero and covariance matrix $$\Sigma=\sigma^2\left(X'X\right)^{-1}.$$
Now note that the (2,3) element of $\Sigma$ is zero, therefore the covariance between $\widehat{\beta}_1$ and $\widehat{\beta}_2$ is zero and since these two quantities are jointly normally distributed, they are by definition independent.

Comment: Thank you ! I'm glad it was as straightforward as looking to calculate the covariance matrix. I just have to remember what that matrix encodes. I appreciate your time and help. (=

Comment: the pleasure is of course mine!